# Exception handling: Is finally executed after throw?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

Assume you have the following code:

Instead of doing:

```
Try
    '
    ' Initialize some objects
    '

    '
    ' do something that fails
    '

    '
    ' Clean up-code that gets not reached because exception
    '
Catch e As Exception
    '
    'Clean up initialized objects
    '

    Throw e
End Try
```

I would like to do:

```
Try
    '
    ' Initialize some objects
    '

    '
    ' do something that fails
    '
Catch e As Exception
    Throw e
Finally
    '
    'Clean up initialized objects
    '
End Try
```

So my simple question is: In case of an exception is the finally block reached even if there is a throw some lines before?

**[EDIT]**
Thanks for your fast answers.

In first line there will be NullReference-, COM- and FileNotFound-Exceptions I think.

Ok, I will go for this code:

```
Try
    '
    ' Initialize some objects
    '

    '
    ' do something that fails
    '
Catch e As Exception      ' or just "Catch"??        
    Throw
Finally
    '
    'Clean up initialized objects
    '
End Try
```

All the best!

Inno

Comment: You shouldn't write `Throw e` but just `Throw`. Otherwise, you reset the exception stack trace, so you lose the information about where the exception was raised initially

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> So my simple question is: In case of an exception is the finally block reached even if there is a throw some lines before?

Yes. The [`Finally` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78bkyd5z%28VS.71%29.aspx) is *always*<sup>1)</sup> executed and exists precisely for clean-up. In your code, remove the `Catch` block, it does nothing. Worse, it actually destroys the stack trace because you don’t re-throw the original exception, you throw a new one.

If you really need a `Catch` block that then re-throws the exception, use the following:

```
Catch e As XyzException
    ' … do some stuff. '
    Throw
End Try
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>: Caveat emptor: there are some exceptions such as `StackOverflowException` (how fitting …) which require special attention and may not trigger the `Finally` block. Handling them correctly is usually quite difficult.

Comment: Konrad - Finally is not always executed. It will not get executed when you have an OutOfMemoryException for instance.

Comment: @Pete: right, but these are specific edge cases (but I should have mentioned them).

Comment: @Pete: Don't you mean StackOverflowException. It is quiet easy to make a test where finally is run in case of an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Brian: have you done a test? If so, I’ll change my posting to `SOE`. This one really cannot be recovered – `OOME` doesn’t make as much sense. I don’t have .NET installed on my Mac though so I can’t test it myself.

Comment: @Konrad: I can't say if an OOME will ever prevent a finally block from running, but I haven't heard that before. It is however, easy to construct a case where it will run, so Pete's point is not strictly correct. SOE on the other hand will take down the runtime so as far as I am aware that will always prevent finally blocks from running.

Comment: @Brian: The Reliability Best Practices page on MSDN suggests that OOME, SOE, TAE and AppDomain unloads can all prevent the `finally` block from running. Some can be mitigated by using constrained execution regions, but in the case of SOE you need to use the `ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` method instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228970.aspx

Comment: @Luke: Thanks for the update and the link. I wasn't aware of OOME could do this. However, it is not the same as "it will not be executed when you have an OOME", which was what I was trying to clarify.

Comment: @Konrad: I would say "Code following a 'finally' clause will not execute without the 'finally' clause executing first.  It's possible for a thread to get stuck in an endless loop or die and stop executing code altogether, but the code in the finally block will never be 'skipped'."

Answer (score 5):

No, it is NOT guaranteed to run. There are certain exceptions - for example StockOverflowException and OutOfMemoryException - where the execution of a finally block is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, a Finally will execute in a Try/Catch block (notable exceptions including when a StackOverflowException or OutOfMemoryException occur). I am curious though, why you didn't try this out for yourself. A valuable way to learn things is to actually try them out for yourselves - after all, you could end up accepting an answer that is wrong or misleading, and you will labour under this falsehood from that point on.

Comment: I tried this out but my debugger stopped at the throw. I read the documentation and didn't find a hint for my question. I asked this questions to get answers belonging directly to my question and belonging indirectly to it (like hints like "finally is under special circumstances not executed").

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: System.Environment.FastFail method was kill current process/thread immediatly, without execute finally sections.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, finally is executed in any case. (there are only few exceptions - Response.Redirect and some cases with multithreading)